# Does the AVX2 instruction set have an instruction to invert each 16-bit number?

Tags: assembly, avx2

For example,a0......a15,change to -a0,......,-a15
I looked for the official manual, but couldn't find it.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe just subtract from zero?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, there isn't a single instruction that acts in all contexts as the packed equivalent of `neg`. However, if you have a vector of all-zeroes, you can subtract from that using a single instruction.

If you don't have an all-zero vector already, you can obtain one with, e.g., `vpxor`:

```
vpxor xmm7, xmm7, xmm7
```

and then you can use `vpsubw` to subtract your 16-bit numbers from the all-zero vector, to produce minus those numbers (here, I'm taking the inputs from `ymm1` and outputting them in `ymm2`, using `ymm7` as the all-zero vector):

```
vpsubw ymm2, ymm7, ymm1
```

You can produce your all-zero register once and then use the same register for multiple subtractions, as long as you don't change its value from zero (e.g. if you have a loop that negates a huge number of 16-bit numbers, you can create a zero register before the loop and just use `vpsubw` on its own to negate numbers inside the loop). So this method negates your numbers with a single instruction, plus one instruction of setup.

Note that `vpxor` on an `xmm` register zeroes the top half of the corresponding `ymm` register, so you can zero an entire `ymm` register by `xor`ing the `xmm` register with itself.

Comment: Correct, AVX2 doesn't have a SIMD version of `neg` or `not`.  Subtract-from-zero or XOR-with-ones is the standard way.  (AVX-512 `vpernlogd` can `not` without needing a vector constant, but still no new instruction to subtract-from-zero.  And `vpternlogd` is a 3-input instruction so you can't copy-and-not without a false dependency.)